# Using scrapy for nested tables

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get data from nested tables, I need to get only rows of each level at a time and loop through them as I make my way down to the nested tables. The table, row and column tags don't have any attributes which makes it hard to identify.

Example:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
     <!-- first level rows -->
      <tr>
         <td>
           ...clipped...
         <td>
         <td>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  <!-- second level rows -->
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        ...clipped...
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
           ...clipped...
         <td>
         <td>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  <!-- second level rows -->
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        ...clipped...
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see in example there are 2 levels of table rows, I need to loop through the first level of rows then have a nested loop to go through the second level of rows.

How do I just get the first level of rows from the response using `css selector` or `xpath`?

I have tried `response.css('tr')` which gives me all the rows in the responses (not just the first level rows).

I have also tried `response.css('tr:first-child')` which does give me 2 nodes, but they aren't the first level rows for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do I just get the first level of rows from the response using css selector or xpath?

Following can give you the iterable :

```
for row in response.css('tbody>tr'):
    #your extracion code goes here
```